# How to change the return value of a method in Intellij?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, return-value

How can I change the return value of a method in Intellij?

The method's value is not set to a variable so there is not work around it.

Comment: Could you maybe clarify what you are asking for with a code snippet? And what does IntelliJ have to do with the method?

Comment: snippet:
int foo() {
    Random r = new Random();
    return r.nextInt(100);
}

if(foo() % 2 == 0) {
   System.out.println("even");
}
else {
   System.out.println("odd");
}

I no longer have the original code. But this snippet explains the problem. 

If you look at the 'if' clause, I want to know what did the foo() method returned. When it's assigned to a variable, then I can check the variable's value. But, if it's used like in this snippet, then, I can't check what foo() has returned.

Comment: So you say you can't assign the result of foo() to a variable before the if clause but you want to be able to know the result of foo() inside and after the if clause? Can you just declare a variable (without initializing it) before the if clause or is that not possible either?

Comment: He's obviously talking about during debugging code he does not have the source for. While we can simulate what the method does by putting entire method into Code Evaluator mode, I doubt the runtime value returned can be altered during debug.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is as close as you can get to storing the result of `foo()` inside your if condition:

```
int result;
if((result = foo()) % 2 == 0){
    System.out.println(result + " is even.");
}else{
    System.out.println(result + " is odd.");
}
```

You can't actually declare `result` inside the condition, you have to do that before.